# Handle data of big JSON file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have big JSON file it is about 4 million line this is structure :

```js
{
 "name": "...",
 "type": "personal_chat",
 "id": 1744378997,
 "messages": [

  //some data here

 ]
}
```

I want make a chat and I have this chat I want to make as JSON file, I want put this data in UI (design) to display it perfectly for user,
**Problem: The file is very big as I said it about 4,400,000 line and about 300,000 objects in `messages array`, How can I load data when user is swipe up because it's impossible to put all this data when user is open website**

- The last object in `messages array` should put in the first of the chat. It is the last message!

Comment: A 4 million line JSON file is a database. Use a server. If it’s just for a design prototype, then get rid of 95% of the file

Comment: In addition to @Adam: If you already have that data from a database, use a pagination strategy and only load a smaller subset of the messages.

Comment: I already downloaded the data from the Telegram server (database), the JSON file I am talking about is the file that I already downloaded from a database of Telegram.